# Cordys data aggregation

Tags: cordys-opentext

How to perform aggregation of data on cordys platform? I have not seen any variable of buffer that can hold the data while an iteration is in progress and finally when the iteration is over the collected data can be persisted to DB in a batch update.

Comment: In a Business Process Model you can iterate and aggregate over data. Use while or for each loop and you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, there are no defined aggregation methods available in cordys.
You can use **while or for each loop** which is available in cordys BPM or you can directly code in java and do further processing as per your business logic.